# Get sizes of registry hives using WMI

Tags: windows, vbscript, registry, wmi

I want to find out the file sizes of the hives in the registry using WMI and VBScript. This is what I have so far:

```
const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
strComputer = "."
Set objReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\"&_ 
    strComputer & "\root\cimv2:StdRegProv")
strKeyPath = "System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Hivelist"
objReg.EnumValues HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, arrVals, arrTypes
WScript.Echo "Values under System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Hivelist"
For Each val In arrVals
    objReg.GetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, val, dwValue
    WScript.Echo dwValue
Next
```

This gives me the correct list, but then I need to get the file sizes. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

1. To avoid type prefix fraud and meaningless variable names, use `strRFSpec` instead of `dwValue`
2. Convert the registry file spec (e.g. `"\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Documents and Settings\NetworkService\NTUSER.DAT"`) into a `strFSpec` understandable to the FileSystemObject (e.g. `"C:\Documents and Settings\NetworkService\NTUSER.DAT"`)
3. Check existence and accessability of `strFSpec`
4. `WScript.Echo goFS.GetFile(strFSpec).Size`

(tested under Win XP)

**ADDED (wrt comment):**

The conversion from `strRFSpec` to `strFSpec` may need more effort than a simple `Replace()` using hardcoded strings. Your `Documents and Settings` or your `WINDOWS` could live on `F:\`. So maybe you'll have to look for a WMI class that maps `"\Device\HarddiskVolume...` to a drive letter, to use %windir% on `strFSpecs` containing `\system\`, or ask `WshShell.SpecialFolders("MyDocuments")` for a drive letter. As my setup is simple, I can't give further - tested - advice.

Comment: Do you mean that I should find/replace "\Device\HarddiskVolume1\" with "C:\", or whatever drive letter it has been given, and then open that path?

Comment: @Lars - for a proof of concept script, a simple `Replace(strRFSpec, "\De..", "C:\")` is probably ok, for a production version, I'd prefer a more reliable look up (WMI, %windir%, SpecialFolders).

Comment: The string replace does indeed work, although I'm still confused about your "production" example. Could you please elaborate with a more full example?